# How to insert from two lists into a list of dictionaries with identical keynames in Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am a newbie to Python and dictionaries. Using Python 3.6.1. I have googled similar issues, but it seems like solutions that others use involve dictionaries with different keys, and that many answers are related to older versions of Python. Any help is appreciated!

I have the following list of dictionaries that returns this when printed:

```
[{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}, 
{'Coordinate': array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}]
```

I have the following lists from which I want to insert the values into the above list of dictionaries:

```
coordkeys = ['Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate']

coordvalues = [[44,33], [55,22], [77,66], [88,99], [77,11], [46,78], [44,33], [13,92], [21,69], [79,91]]

heightkeys = ['Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height']

heightvalues = [333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 222, 2222, 3333]
```

From these lists I want to insert the values into the list of dictionaries. So that the result follows the following pattern: 
the first entry of the first valuelist will correspond to the first value of the second valuelist (where both end up in the same dictionary). 
Obviously I would wish to not use the coordkeys, and heightkeys lists if that is possible.

To illlustrate the pattern the end result will have, with all the values from both lists, the end result starts as follows:

`[{'Coordinate': [44,33], 'Height': 333}, 
    {'Coordinate': [55,22], 'Height': 444}, 
    # And so on until the end of both lists
    ]`

I tried to play with only one list as follows:

```
geographic_details = dict(list(zip(coordkeys, coordvalues)))
```

But a print of the output returns only the last entry from the coordinate-values list, and not all of the values from the list:

```
{'Coordinate': [79, 91]}
```

So obviously only the last key-value pair is kept, because there are several keys with the same name. zip or this way of using zip seems like not the way to go here.

EDIT:

I tried adding from both lists by doing this, but it seems like this is not allowed.:

This last line of code missed an ending parenthesis. Now I added it so it looks like this:

```
geographic_details = dict(list(zip(coordkeys, coordvalues), zip(heightkeys, heightvalues)))
```

However a new error is returned:

```
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: `geographic_details = dict(list(zip(coordkeys, coordvalues), zip(heightkeys, heightvalues)))`

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed that now. New error appears now, see EDIT.

Comment: Please don't progressively ask about every problem in your code in one question. Ask one specific question in each post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this ?

```
import numpy as np
numpy_array=[{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None},
{'Coordinate': np.array([None, None], dtype=object), 'Height': None}]


coordkeys = ['Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate']

coordvalues = [[44,33], [55,22], [77,66], [88,99], [77,11], [46,78], [44,33], [13,92], [21,69], [79,91]]

heightkeys = ['Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height']

heightvalues = [333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 222, 2222, 3333]

for index,value in enumerate(zip(coordvalues,heightvalues)):
    for index_1,value_1 in enumerate(numpy_array):
        for key,value_2 in value_1.items():
            if index==index_1:
                if isinstance(value_2,np.ndarray):
                    value_2[0]=value[0][0]
                    value_2[1]=value[0][1]
                value_1['Height']=value[1]

print(numpy_array)
```

output:

```
[{'Height': 333, 'Coordinate': array([44, 33], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 444, 'Coordinate': array([55, 22], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 555, 'Coordinate': array([77, 66], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 666, 'Coordinate': array([88, 99], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 777, 'Coordinate': array([77, 11], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 888, 'Coordinate': array([46, 78], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 999, 'Coordinate': array([44, 33], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 222, 'Coordinate': array([13, 92], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 2222, 'Coordinate': array([21, 69], dtype=object)}, {'Height': 3333, 'Coordinate': array([79, 91], dtype=object)}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are equal sized lists `map` function looks like the most elegant way of creating the desired data structure.

```
coordkeys = ['Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate', 'Coordinate']
coordvalues = [[44,33], [55,22], [77,66], [88,99], [77,11], [46,78], [44,33], [13,92], [21,69], [79,91]]
heightkeys = ['Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height', 'Height']
heightvalues = [333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999, 222, 2222, 3333]


def convert(c, cval, h, hval):
    return {c:cval, h:hval}

assert list(map(convert, coordkeys, coordvalues, heightkeys, heightvalues)) == [{'Coordinate': [44, 33], 'Height': 333}, 
    {'Coordinate': [55, 22], 'Height': 444}, 
    {'Coordinate': [77, 66], 'Height': 555},
    {'Coordinate': [88, 99], 'Height': 666},
    {'Coordinate': [77, 11], 'Height': 777}, 
    {'Coordinate': [46, 78], 'Height': 888}, 
    {'Coordinate': [44, 33], 'Height': 999}, 
    {'Coordinate': [13, 92], 'Height': 222}, 
    {'Coordinate': [21, 69], 'Height': 2222}, 
    {'Coordinate': [79, 91], 'Height': 3333}]
```